# Como saber se a posição do scroll está em cima de uma section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Não sei se ficou claro, mas vou exemplificar, Eu tenho varias sections no meu site, e quando der scroll eu queria realizar alguns efeitos com Javascript, como eu faço para para saber quando exatamente o usuário estará visualizando a div, como no Scroll Spy do Boostrap? Eu tentei o pageYoffset, mas as medidas variam de acordo com a resolução.

Answer (score 5):

você pode usar o `getBoundingClientRect` par apegar a posição atual de um elemento na tela.

```js
//todas as paginas ocupam toda a tela.
var pages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.page'), 0);
var checkCurrentPage = function () {
  // obtendo posição das paginas.
  var tops = pages.map(function (page) {
    var position = page.getBoundingClientRect();
    return position.top;
  });
  
  var indexUnique = tops.indexOf(0);
  if (indexUnique != -1) {
    // unica pagina sendo exibida;
    console.log([pages[indexUnique]]);
    return;
  } else {
    // obtendo as paginas que começam acima da posição atual.
    var prevs = tops.filter(function (top) {
      return top < 0;
    });
  
    var prev = pages[prevs.length - 1];
    var next = pages[prevs.length];
    console.log([ prev, next ]);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", checkCurrentPage);
window.addEventListener("resize", checkCurrentPage);
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.page1 {
  background-color: #009688
}

.page2 {
  background-color: #FF9800
}

.page3 {
  background-color: #673AB7
}
```

```html
<div class="page page1">
</div>
<div class="page page2">
</div>
<div class="page page3">
</div>
```

se precisar saber se um determinado elemento está dentro do viewport atual (mesmo que apenas parcialmente), então você deve comparar o retorno do `getBoundingClientRect` com o `window.innerWidth` e `window.innerHeight`.

```
var position = page.getBoundingClientRect();
var vpWidth = window.innerWidth;
var vpHeight = window.innerHeight;

var visibleY = (position.top <= 0 && position.bottom > 0) || (position.top > 0 && position.top < vpHeight);
var visibleX = (position.left <= 0 && position.right > 0) || (position.left > 0 && position.left < vpWidth);

return visibleY && visibleX;
```

Se o elemento precisar está completamente visível dentro da tela.:

```
var position = page.getBoundingClientRect();
var vpWidth = window.innerWidth;
var vpHeight = window.innerHeight;

var visibleY = position.top >= 0 && position.bottom <= vpHeight;
var visibleX = position.left >= 0 && position.right <= vpWidth;

return visibleY && visibleX;
```

Answer (score 4):

Basta verificar se o [scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) é maior ou igual que o [position().top](https://api.jquery.com/position/) da seção que tu quer verificar, o `scrollTop()` retorna a posição vertical atual da barra de rolagem, o `position().top` a posição do elemento em relação ao seu pai.

*Nota que no exemplo eu verifico se a posição do scroll esta entre o *início da seção de interesse* e o *início da próxima seção*, ou seja, garantindo que está sobre a seção correta.

*Note também que nesse contexto o [offset().top](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) também funcionaria, pois o elemento pai das `section's` é o próprio *document*.

Segue um snippet de exemplo:

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  console.clear();
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#section1').position().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= $('#section2').position().top) {
    console.log("secao1");
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#section2').position().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= $('#section3').position().top) {
    console.log("secao2");
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#section3').position().top) {
    console.log("secao3");
  }
})
```

```css
section {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section1"></section>
<section id="section2"></section>
<section id="section3"></section>
```